# How do i show this equality without using reccurence method:$\prod_{k=0}^{k=n}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2^k}}={\frac {\sin\theta}{2^n\sin(2^{-n}\theta)}}$??

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to show this without using reccurence method for all $n$ $\in $ $\mathbb{N}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ :

$${\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}\cos\frac{\theta}{2^2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2^3}\cdots \cos\frac{\theta}{2^n} ={\frac {\sin\theta}{2^n\sin(2^{-n}\theta)}} $$

**Note**: I have used many trigonomitrics transformations but i can't succed !!
$$\prod_{k=0}^{k=n}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2^k}}={\frac {\sin\theta}{2^n\sin(2^{-n}\theta)}}$$

Thank you for any help

Comment: So you don't want any sort of inductive proof?

Comment: hop to get a method with trigonometric transformation if it is possible !!!

Comment: Don't you just have to apply the half-angle formula for sine n times?

Comment: I used it but i can't as i cited in my note above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that:

\begin{align}
2\cos x\sin x&=\sin 2x\\
\implies \cos x&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin x}
\end{align}

Then, given an integer number $n>0$ we have

$$\cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cdot \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)\cdot \ldots \cdot \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\cdot \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2^2}\right)}\cdot \ldots\cdot \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2^{n-1}}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}$$

Which is a "telescopic product", and the inequality follows from here.

Comment: it is a good idea but how d i can complet from your last step ?

Comment: In the RHS the numerator of the $(k+1)$-th fraction is identical to the denominator of the $k$-th fraction ($1<k\le n$), and they reduce to 1, so we eventualy get
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{\sin  \theta}{\sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2^n}\right)}$$

Comment: great , thank you very much , i didn't  got attention for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use induction for this proof.

First show it is true for $n=1$

Then assume it is true for some $n=k$

Then prove that this implies it is also true for $n=k+1$

In the first and last steps you will need to make use of a standard trigonometric transformation.

---

---

Another approach is to keep using the transformation of $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ as follows:$$\sin(\theta)=2\color{red}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$$$$=2^2\color{red}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2^2})}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2^2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$$$$=2^3\color{red}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2^3})}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2^3})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2^2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$$$$=\dots$$$$=2^n\color{red}{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2^n})}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2^n})\dots\cos(\frac{\theta}{2^2})\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

The answer follows from here.

Comment: @MarioG,yes of course